# In excel "Optional parent and mandatory child element issue" while exporting XML

Tags: excel, xsd

Can some one please help me on the below issue.

We are trying to export an xml from Excel as per a schema.
The issue is that, in the schema there is an Parent Element - which is optional (Name it as A) and it contains 3 child elements(A1, A2 and A3) in which one child element(A3) is an mandatory. When no value is given to the all the child elements of A (optional parent), it is throwing an error when exporting XML because of the A3(mandatory chile element) even though it's parent element(A) is Optional. We are expecting no error should be thrown, while exporting XML. Is there a work around for this issue.

The structure looks like below,

A (Optional - Complex Element)
-> A1 (Optioanl – Child element of A), A2 (Optioanl – Child element of A) and A3 (Mandatory – Child Element of A).

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: If A is optional then the node (and three child nodes) can exist or not. If A exists, then three child nodes are expected. You would have to make A1, A2 and A3 optional if A existed but was only partially complete.

Comment: So, it is not possible to export an XML  when value is not given to the child Elements(out of which one is mandatory - A3) of A, eventhough A is made optional Complex element? The only way is to make all the child elements optional in that case?